# Problem on Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have no idea where to start for the following problem:

$E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that for all $x \in E$, we have $$ \lim_{h\searrow 0} \frac{m(E\cap [x-h,x+h])}{2h} = 1$$ What if $x \notin E$?

I think it has something to do with Vitali Covering Lemma.

Comment: If $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure then it is not true. E.g. let $E$ be a singleton.

Comment: Is the question correct,  Take$E=\Q $ ,its measure is 0 hence numerator is always 0

Comment: You need m(E) not 0 too.

Comment: I think the question will be  $m(E) > 0 $ and for some $x$ in $E$ actually the $ m(R) $ $ R=\{x: $satisying the condition $\}$ is $m(E)  $

Comment: The statement is true for *almost every* $x \in E$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to prove is just [Lebesgue's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) in $\mathbb R$.
By choosing $f=\chi_E$ in the statement of [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), we get that, for **almost every** $x \in E$,
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{m(B(x,h))} \int_{B(x,h)}\chi_E(y)\,dy=\chi_E(x).
$$
since $B(x,h)=(x-h,x+h)$, $\int_{B(x,h)}\chi_E(y)\,dy= m((x-h,x+h) \cap E)$ and $\chi_E(x)=1$ for every $x \in E$, we can rewrite this as
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{m((x-h,x+h) \cap E)}{m(B(x,h))} =1,
$$

which is what we wanted.
If $x \notin E$, apply the same reasoning and remember that $\chi_E(x)=0$ in that case.